# appindexing play services plugin i.e play-services-appindexing:8.4.0.aar file in a way to avoid crossing 65k limit

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins

Hi Currently i have implemented App indexing,deep linking in my Game , but it is developed by using whole google-play-services.jar file by which the API level is getting increased, so where can i get particular  play-services-appindexing:8.4.0.aar file in a way to maintain the Max API levels ?

Comment: Why you are adding .aar file?? instead of that you can add required API in your build.gradle dependency rit?
Please go through this  https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

Comment: Ya. right but , even after adding required API in build gradle , it shows ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/appindexing/AppIndex in log  runtime error and a Crash in Unity .. so i found solution that it should be added in Unity's Plugins/Android directory.

Comment: share your build.gradle file...

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here- apply plugin: 'com.android.library'android {
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/BCKEY.DSA'
    exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.xml'
    exclude 'META-INF/BCKEY.SF'
    exclude 'AUTHORS'
}
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
sourceSets {
    main {
        //Path to your <span id="IL_AD2" class="IL_AD">source code</span>
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
        }
    }
}
defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    multiDexEnabled = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

}

```
enter code here- dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile files('release/AppIndexingPlugin.jar')}
```